# How do I do "io.read" twice on one variable after inputting the wrong type?

Tags: lua

Heyo. I'm pretty new to Lua (although I do code with Java), so I don't really know anything on this. I'm basically trying to get a user's input, and if it's not the right type, then restart. Now, I'm not sure if it's just Lua or my IDE (I'm using ZeroBrane Studio if that helps), but it won't reinput for whatever reason. (it just loops, meaning it skips the io.read line)

```
::restart::
...
a = io.read("*number")
if unit == nil then
  print("Error! Incorrect Input!\nRestarting...")
  goto restart
end
```

Oh, and yes, I'm using goto commands for restart. I thought that might be what's causing the issue, but I also tried this:

```
a = io.read("*number") --input non-number
print(a)               --prints
a = io.read("*number") --skips
print(a)               --prints
```

When you input a number, it doesn't skip.

Any help would be nice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not use "goto" voodoo...

Comment: If there's a better/simpler way to restart, I'm more than happy to use it.

Answer (score 1):

nvm i solved it myself

```
local a
repeat
  a = io.read(); a = tonumber(a)
  if not a then
    print("Incorrect Input!\n(Try using only numbers)")
  end
until a
```

Comment: this is a very good solution. But my advice to split it of onto an own function still stands.

Answer (score 0):

```
::restart::
local a = io.read("*n", "*l")
if a == nil then
   io.read("*l")  -- skip the erroneous input line
   print("Error! Incorrect Input!\nRestarting...")
   goto restart
end
```

P.S.
Feel free to use `goto` whenever it makes your code more understandable.
For example, using `while` of `repeat-until` loop in this code wouldn't make it better (you would need either additional local variable or `break` statement).

Comment: This answer encourages (especially beginners) the use of bad practices, and should therefore be avoided. A loop needs an additional control variable but is less error prone and more robust.

Comment: @Mischa - Why do you consider `goto` a bad practice while sometimes it could be useful?  Please show how would you rewrite my code without `goto` so that the code become better.  While you don't have such example, your recommendation (to always avoid `goto`s) should be considered as opinion-based (and not suitable for SO).

Comment: `goto` is a "tool" that should be used with caution. In the case of op, what happens when he later wants to check just another user input? will he restart the whole thing if one of any inputs failed? 1) Let's asume the user has to input 10+ different values (sometimes text, sometimes numbers) and he accidentaly fucks up the 11th input... I would be mad if I had to do everything again. | 2) He has to repeat the validation code for every input | 3) If he later decides to not copy and paste the validation code he has to make it a function anyway... So better do it right the first time.

Comment: @Mischa - I agree that sometimes (but not always) goto is a "bad thing". What about THIS task?  Could you REWRITE my code to make it better without `goto`?

Comment: @Mischa Sorry for the late reply, but the code I'm using is only getting 1-3 inputs, all from the beginning. If I wanted to make it more user-friendly, I'd just go back instead of restarting. As for validation code, I can easily just make a function. It isn't that hard to copy and paste.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the built-in filter of `io.read()` (which I do think is bugged sometimes) you should consider using an own little function to ensure that the correct data will be give by the user.

This is such a function:

```
function --[[ any ]] GetUserInput(--[[ string ]] expectedType, --[[ string ]] errorText)
  local --[[ bool ]] needInput = true
  local --[[ any ]] input = nil

  while needInput do
    input = GetData()

    if ( type(input) == expectedType ) then
      needInput = false
    else
      print(errorText)
    end
  end

  return input

end
```

You can then call it with:

```
local userInput = GetUserInput("number", "Error: Incorrect Input! Please give a number.")
```

*Oh and on a sidenote: Goto is considered bad practice.*

Comment: This code doesn't comply with Lua syntax.  Is it a pseudo-code?

Comment: it should do... Maybe I made a mistake somehwere, I can't test it here atm

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You were right, the code was wrong. I fixed it now